# Sthala Purana of Varadaraja Perumal Kanchipuram

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

Varadaraja Perumal Temple is an important site for Sri Vaishnavas, because it is one of the 108 Divya Deshas and Bhagwad Ramanujacharya under guidance of Bhagwan Varadaraja Swamy.

- What is the story of the origin of Varadaraja Perumal temple in
  Kanchipuram,
- What is the sthala purana for Varadaraja Perumal temple.